# Search through meta array in database field

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a database field named meta that stored a set of datetimes in this format

```
date_approved"=>"2015-01-01T10:19:44+00:00", "date_realized"=>"2015-01-01T10:31:11+00:00", "date_tn_approved"=>"2015-01-01T10:09:40+00:00"
```

Is it possible to have a SQL Query to Select for example all the records where date_approved are in January?

I  not handle the insertion of values into the database so I can't really change much in the manner the data is stored

Comment: you can search for `datepart(mm,date_approved)` in `where` clause

Comment: The entire string is actually part of one field, so can't do that

Comment: is this entry for one id... ?... you should rethink of data modeling ..

Comment: You really have the complete string as shown in **one** single column? Including the commas and the `=>` sign? That is a horrible way to store your information.

Comment: @POHH: there is no `datepart` in Postgres. It's either `date_part('month', ...)` or the standard SQL compliant `extract(month from ...)`

Comment: It is :/ we really have no control of this database. It seems to be a rails app that is storing it this way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the data is really stored in the way you show us, then this can be achieved using a [`hstore`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/hstore.html) because that value can directly be cast to a `hstore`:

```
select *
from the_table
where extract(month from ((meta::hstore -> 'date_approved')::timestamp)) = 1
```

This will fail if the format in the column isn't exactly as you have shown us or if the timestamps are formatted in a different way.

You might need to [create](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createextension.html) the `hstore` extension to be able to use that:

```
create extension hstore;
```

This needs to be done as the superuser.

SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/d41d8/4408